# Как заполнить StringGrid?

Tags: delphi

Делаю таблицу под тип "лист заказа". Пользователь может сформировать таблицу заказа в программе (временную) , которую потом можно будет записать в базу. Подскажите пожалуйста, как заполнить таблицу (StringGrid)? Заполнение должно происходить так: Кнопка "Добавить строчку" -> заполняем Edit -> Занесение в таблицу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заполнить таблицу? Если можно примером кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить строку:

```
StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.RowCount + 1;
```

Заполнить:

```
StringGrid1.Cells[i, j] := данные_преобразованные_в_string;
```

`i` - номер столбца(колонки) от `0` до `StringGrid1.ColCount-1`. Первые `StringGrid1.FixedCols` столбцов - это заголовки строки (серые столбцы слева от таблицы). Может быть и 0.
`j` - номер строки от `0` до `StringGrid1.RowCount-1`. Первые `StringGrid1.FixedRows` строк - это заголовки столбца. Может быть и 0.

Допустим, у вас нет заголовков строк. Тогда код может быть примерно таким

```
procedure insert;
var lastRow: integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.RowCount := StringGrid1.RowCount + 1;
  lastRow := StringGrid1.RowCount - 1;
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, lastRow] := Edit1.Text;
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, lastRow] := Edit2.Text;
  StringGrid1.Cells[2, lastRow] := Edit3.Text;
end
```